# Better practice to link to images in root directory or uploaded images in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image

finally almost done creating my first official site. Converting it to wordpress soon.

Is it better to link to images that I have in my root folder of my site >

```
background: url(images/picture.jpg);
```

or is it better to upload the photos into wordpress and then link to the image there?

```
 background: url(wordpresssite.com/xx/xx/xxx/xxx/image.jpg);
```

Is there any better reason to do one over the other. Any SEO benefits, any reason one should be done.

I would like to keep all my images in images folder rather than upload them all into wordpress and link to them that way.

Comment: If you ever change your domain name (from `wordpresssite.com` to `coolername.io`) you will have to change all links if you go with the second option

Answer (score 1):

if those images are part of theme you created and they wouldn't change in the future, I would recommend you to store them in **theme folder** subfolder **img**

---

Structure of the fies:
THEME FOLDER
CSS FOLDER
IMG FOLDER

---

In this way you could use them in your css file like so:
background-image: url(../img/picture.jpg);